# Trimble Export AgData, how to separate passes and tracks

Tags: trimble-maps

When we do data export in Trimble format using Trimble SDK (Trimble.Ag.FarmModel),

for different types of adaptive curves (tracks, headland passes) we do the following:

**for AgGPS format**, when we create feature, we add AttributesTable to it, which has a property of ID. And now, when we want headland pass and tracks, to be at the same time on the screen on the machine, we give it the same ID 1517. If we want it to be displayed separately on a machine, we give it different ID, like 1517 for passes and 1527 for tracks.

**My question is**, how do we do the same thing for AgData format?
In AgData case, we create a Landmark and adding it to the Field. Landmark has several properties, but no IDs, which Landmark property do I use, to display passes and tracks separately or together on a machine?